Node js 22.12.0 , Unable to create React project using - npx create-react-app
Keep getting dependency error. Added screenshot
MY Node and npm version is as below -
PS D:\source> npx create-react-app react-project  --legacy-peer-deps
Creating a new React app in D:\source\react-project.
Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts with cra-template...
added 1320 packages in 27s
265 packages are looking for funding
run npm fund for details
Initialized a git repository.
Installing template dependencies using npm...
npm error code ERESOLVE
npm error ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm error
npm error While resolving: -project@0.1.0
npm error Found: react@19.0.0
npm error node_modules/react
npm error   react@"^19.0.0" from the root project
npm error
npm error Could not resolve dependency:
npm error peer react@"^18.0.0" from @testing-library/react@13.4.0
npm error node_modules/@testing-library/react
npm error   @testing-library/react@"^13.0.0" from the root project
npm error
npm error Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm error this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
npm error to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm error
npm error
npm error For a full report see:
npm error C:\Users\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2024-12-19T19_12_55_915Z-eresolve-report.txt
PS D:\source> node -v
v22.12.0
PS D:\source> npm -v
10.9.0
PS D:\source>
enter image description here

Honestly, if you're creating a new application from scratch, don't use create-react-app.  There are more current/supported options.

Thank You @David is their any other way than next , i have certain restriction on what i can use

Use npm i  --legacy-peer-deps after an error. You can downgrade react to 18 in the project to make it compatible. Vite is the recommended way for new project, but you can still use CRA if you want, it's obsolete but workable
